How to organize http client requests authorization via spnego?
I am trying to authenticate on remote sever with kerberos, using http4s scala client.
After researching this tech, I realised that.

Firstly I need to make some empty request to server with no special headers
than server should answer with 401, and empty header WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
(with no token)
Client has to response with header

Authorization: Negotiate DDDDfffffEEEE_SomeGeneratedTokenHere_AAAAddddCCC
(this token and it's header is generated with:
val manager = GSSManager.getInstance()
val principal = "myprincipal@here"
val krbOid = new Oid (1.2.840.113554.1.2.2)
val serverName: GSSName = manager.createName(principal, krbOid)

val creds: GSSCredential = manager.createCredential(serverName, GSSContext.INDEFINITE_LIFETIME, krbOid, GSSContext.DEFAULT_LIFETIME)
val ctx: GSSContext = manager.createContext(creds)

val token = ctx.initSecContext(Array.emptyByteArray, 0, 0)
val headerValue = "Negotiate ${Base64.getEncoder.encodeString(token)}"
val headerName = "Authorization"
val header = Header(headerName, headerValue)



Then Server must (as I understood) respond with its token in header, but there are no any tokens in headers.
Server just responds with 401 and header WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, with no server token in it, as ignoring my client header's token.
With message:  the resource requires authentication which was not supplied by request

What is the problem? And can I authenticate with separate requests and regular httpclient calls this way at all, or maybe I missed something important?

What OS is the client running on? How do you initialize the GSSAPI context? Which mechanism and which target SPN do you specify?


OS, - unix system, 2) in a standard gssapi java way (I am sure that my token is correct, cause context produce it from ccache(if no correct cache, it fails with an Exception)) 3) spn - does it matter? (mechanism - krb5oid - you mean?)


updated question in order to show how context initiated and principal used


the SPN matters a lot, the client needs to know the SPN assigned to the server, as Kerberos needs to find a matching secret key. Currently, are you specifying the user principal or the server principal for the GSSName?


As principal value I use my user principal name

If I configure principal name wrong the application fails with an error, so, I am sure it is correct, cause it does not fail and it generates byte array as token when ctx.initSecContext() invoked

No, that's not enough to draw the conclusion – it will give you a token when any existing principal is given as the SPN, but that doesn't mean it will give you an acceptable token, and the fact that your server doesn't accept it pretty much counters this.



Firstly I need to make some empty request to server with no special headers


If you know that the server will require SPNEGO, feel free to skip steps 1 & 2 – they give you no additional information, and they have no effect on the connection state (as there is no connection state in HTTP), so you can avoid the unnecessary round-trip and immediately include the SPNEGO token in your request.

As principal value I use my user principal name

That's correct for GSSCredential, but not correct for GSSContext – to create an initiator (client) context, createContext() needs to receive the server's principal name as first parameter.
By providing your own GSSCredential to createContext(), what you're currently doing is asking the JRE to create an acceptor (server) context, which happens to work because Kerberos is symmetric like that (i.e. users can be services and vice versa), but the token you get is a "server->client" token that doesn't make sense to be sent to another server. To quote the Java SE documentation:

createContext(GSSCredential myCred)
"Factory method for creating a context on the acceptor's side."

createContext(GSSName peer, Oid mech, GSSCredential myCred, int lifetime)
"Factory method for creating a context on the initiator's side."


Note how in the 2nd definition, there is an additional GSSName parameter named peer.
Kerberos tickets (and the tokens created from them) are specialized to the server that will receive them – you can think of it a bit like JWT "audience", although with some cryptography on top so that there are two distinct failure modes between specifying a completely nonexistent SPN versus specifying a SPN that exists but doesn't match the actual service. The former will immediately raise an error (since the KDC cannot issue a ticket), while the latter will seem to work, and you will still get a token of some kind – only the server won't be able to decrypt the token, because it was encrypted using the wrong key.
So you need to create an additional GSSName for the server's SPN, which is a combination of the protocol name (HTTP uses an upper-case HTTP) and the server domain name that you're trying to access (which should be taken directly from the URL):

In the GSS-API svc@host format (might not be compatible with Windows):
manager.createName("HTTP@myapp.example.com", GSSName.NT_HOSTBASED_SERVICE, krbOid)


In the Kerberos svc/host or svc/host@REALM format (compatible with all platforms):
manager.createName("HTTP/myapp.example.com", krbOid)

(though, the actual Kerberos name type OID is slightly different from the Kerberos mechanism OID that you have, but if it happens to work anyway...)


…and then call createContext() using the "initiator" calling convention:
manager.createContext(serviceName, krbOid, myCred, lifetime)



Than Server must(as I understood) response with its token in header,


Yes, but when it comes to HTTP specifically, the return token can be ignored – it could be fed back into the context for mutual authentication, but the way Kerberos is integrated into HTTP doesn't allow it to be of any use (so you have to rely on TLS anyway).


but There are no any tokens in headers. Server just responces with 401 and header WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, with no server token in it, as ignoring my client header's token. With message: the resource requires authentication wich was not supplyied by request


This means incorrect authentication was supplied. Just because you got a token doesn't mean it's the correct token.
How to know whether you have the correct token? The initial client->server token should be quite long – just under a kilobyte when AES is used – and you can use the Python 'pyspnego' module to dump it in text format:
pip install --user pyspnego
cat token.bin | python3 -m spnego

which will show "MessageType: SPNEGO InitialContextToken" and the target service's name under 'Data.ticket.sname'. You can also compare the APIs – this would be the (working) Python equivalent of your Scala code:
ctx = spnego.client(hostname="foo.example.com", service="HTTP", protocol="kerberos")
buf = ctx.step(None)
headers["Authorization"] = "Negotiate " + base64.b64encode(buf).decode()

or
name = gssapi.Name("HTTP@foo.example.com", gssapi.NameType.hostbased_service)
# credential is optional - GSSAPI always uses the 'environment' creds by default
ctx = gssapi.SecurityContext(usage="initiate", name=name)
buf = ctx.step()

